# Node.js callback hellp

Tags: node.js, express, callback

Despite endless SO posts, tutorials, videos and how-to's I can't seem to be able to make my simple callback work. If someone can please let me know where I am off, it would help fill in the gap in my understanding of callbacks. Mine is so simple it's embarrassing. Basically what I am trying to return a query result from mongo (via mongoose) to the calling function.

The calling function:

```
team1 = '2638';
var t = doesTeamExist('team1', function(team){
  console.log(team);
});
```

The processing function:

```
function doesTeamExist(id, res){
    Team.findOne(id).populate('team').exec(function(err,team){
        console.log(team);
        res.team = team;
    });
};
```

I know that the appropriate team is returned in doesTeamExist as my console shows

```
{ _id: 545930dc14a8e3bc9ffab864,
  id: '1532',
  name: 'TEAM1',
  alt_id: '2638',
  created: Fri Nov 07 2014 13:41:43 GMT-0700 (MST) }
```

yet I get a undefined from the calling function. Can anyone see the hole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `res.team = team` you should use `res(team)`.

Comment: Although Miroslav doesn't offer an explanation, his answer is 100% correct.  The reason it will correct your problem is that your passing a function (the callback) to `doesTeamExist` and therefore you need to call it as you would any function `res(team)`.

Comment: I don't understand how this doesn't answer the question? "to make my simple callback work". The problem is in the line I mentioned. `res` parameter in `doesTeamExist` method is passed function from the first code snippet. If you want to pass the queried data there, you have to _call_ the function with the data as its parameter. Therefore line `res(team)` is the answer. Why are you asking for critique or request clarification? The question is clear. (and hopefully the answer too :) )

Answer (score 0):

As Miroslav mentioned using `res(team)` will accomplish what you need, but if you're using express 4.0 you might wanna use `res.status(status_code).send(team)`.

You can check the status codes for the http protocol here:

[HTTP Status Codes from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)